# Constructor Arguments Error when Declaring an Instance of a Class

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I was working on a class to control the power of two DC motors with the Raspberry Pi using the imported `RPi.GPIO` library. The code is as followed:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class Motor:

    def _init_(self, MotorPin):
        self.MotorControlPin = MotorPin
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(self.MotorControlPin, GPIO.OUT)
        self.PWM = GPIO.PWM(self.MotorControlPin, 100)
    def SetPower(self, Power):
        self.PWM.start(Power)
```

When I try to create an instance of the class, `RightMotor = Motor(12)` Python returns the error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module> RightMotor = Motor(12) TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments`

The python IDLE seems to think that the `_init_(self, Motor)` function does not take any arguments. Am I using the function incorrectly? If not, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the constructor method in Python is `__init__`, with two underscores at the beginning and two at the end.  Your code defines `_init_` instead, which as far as Python is concerned is just another ordinary method with no bearing on object construction.

Comment: A careless mistake if I've ever seen one! Thanks for the help!